# Creating AdSet via FB Marketing API

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm trying to create AdSet via FB Marketng API, but getting Error 100 (Invalid parameter). I'm even try to paste sample code from FB Developers Docs, but it is the same Error. Please help.
This is my code:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\Targeting;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\TargetingFields;

$targeting = new Targeting();
$targeting->{TargetingFields::GEO_LOCATIONS} =
  array(
    'countries' => array('US')
  );


/**
 * Step 4 Create the AdSet
 */
use FacebookAds\Object\AdSet;

use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\AdSetBillingEventValues;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\AdSetOptimizationGoalValues;

try{
    $start_time = (new \DateTime("+1 week"))->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
    $end_time = (new \DateTime("+2 week"))->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
    $adset = new AdSet(null, $account_id);
    $adset->setData(array(
        AdSetFields::NAME => 'Adslondon1',
        AdSetFields::CAMPAIGN_ID => '6070381098103',
        AdSetFields::LIFETIME_BUDGET => '50',
        AdSetFields::TARGETING => $targeting,
        AdSetFields::OPTIMIZATION_GOAL => AdSetOptimizationGoalValues::LINK_CLICKS,
        AdSetFields::BILLING_EVENT => AdSetBillingEventValues::LINK_CLICKS,
        AdSetFields::BID_AMOUNT => '10',
        AdSetFields::START_TIME => $start_time,
        AdSetFields::END_TIME => $end_time

    ));

    $adset->create(array(
        AdSet::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => AdSet::STATUS_PAUSED,
    ));

    echo 'AdSet  ID: '. $adset->id . "\n";
}
```

Comment: have you tried this in postman or any rest client?

Comment: I've tried that code in my script only.

Comment: Guys, I've got an aswer! The problem was in Budget and Bid amount. Cents instead of dollars. So, my LIFETIME_BUDGET WAS TOO LOW.

Comment: @AnnG post and answer your own question, then.